# How to read in a list of strings from a .dic file

Tags: python

I am building a guessing game to help me learn python. Its goal is to take my computers dictionary file en_Gb.dic and read it in as a list of strings - pick a random word and then play a varaint of hangman with the user.

The inside of a .dic file will look something like this:

```
abalone/MS
abandon/7LdS
abandoner/M
abandonware
abase/SGLD
abaser/M
abash/LGhSD
abashed/UY
abate/DLGS
abated/U
abater/M
abatis/S
abattoir/SM
```

i.e. a word and then possibly a / followed by some symbols, which the user doesn't need to guess.

Currnetly I've tried

```
F=open(FileAdress,"r")
print(F)
data=F.readlines()
```

but I'm getting an error in data=F.readlines() and my intuition is there will be a more sophisticated method of doing this- as reading in a file as a list of strings is a normal thing to do.

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Moshe/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/scratch_guessing_game.py", line 4, in <module>
    data=F.readlines()
  File "C:\Users\Moshe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 2525: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: your file looks similar to CSV file but it use `/` instead `,` - but you can still use module `csv` to read it using `sep="/"`

Comment: Please add the error in the question.

Comment: Ive added the error! thanks everyone

Comment: do you know what encoding your files uses? if you dont care you can ignore these errors by using `open(FileAdress,"r", errors='ignore')`. However it would be best to use the same encoding to read the file as its encoded in.

Comment: what is the desired output, what do you want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying the encoding while opening the file like this.

```py
file = open(filepath, 'r', encoding='utf8')
```

Or try opening the file as a binary file.

```py
file = open(filepath, 'rb')
```

I don't know what might work without trying to use the actual file that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

so you want to read it and store all the values in a list ? 
if I understand correctly, you can use this Code:

```
with open(Path_to_file, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    print(lines )  # output: ['abalone/MS\n', 'abandon/7LdS\n', 'abandoner/M\n', 'abandonware\n', 'abase/SGLD\n', 'abaser/M\n', 'abash/LGhSD\n', 'abashed/UY\n', 'abate/DLGS\n', 'abated/U\n', 'abater/M\n', 'abatis/S\n', 'abattoir/SM']
```

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I uploaded the answer before he added the error Description. He modified it later and added the Error Description.